# Find locations within a lat/lng bounding box

Tags: php, mapping, latitude-longitude

I have 4 variables:

$southwest_lat, $southwest_lng, $northeast_lat, $northeast_lng

I also have a database table, with fields: Name, Latitude, and Longitude.

```
// First attempt, likely terribly wrong
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE
(Latitude >= '$southwest_lat' AND Latitude <= '$northeast_lat') AND
(Longitude >= '$southwest_lng' AND Longitude <= '$northeast_lng')";
```

How would I find DB items within the boundary box formed by the coordinates?

**EDIT:** Thanks guys, corrected the Longitude part of the query.

Comment: Looks like you've got it already, what's the issue you're seeing? remove the quotes from SQL perhaps?

Comment: @Matt you are checking the latitude AND longitude against just the latitude that you are supplying

Comment: Oops, my bad. I'll test and update the question accordingly.

Comment: @Patrick - the perils of cut-and-paste, methinks :-) Well spotted

Comment: A portion of this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953105/is-it-possible-with-kml-and-google-maps/4955291#4955291 - the bit about polygon intersection?

Comment: @Matt with the typo correction are you still having a problem?

Comment: @MarkBaker I was actually just checking the logic of > & < to make sure the OP had them in the right order.  But I deal A LOT with gps, so I'm good at picking up these types of problems :-)

Comment: Seems like you've solved the problem. What's the final working SQL @Matt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case your application can have `$southwest_lng` > `$northeast_lng` (180 degrees wrap-around, e.g. when using Google Maps), you may want to check that and use a `NOT BETWEEN $northeast_lng AND $southwest_lng` in that case.

Comment: Ah, yes. That's exactly the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Don't get it. What field should I compare to the `NOT BETWEEN`?

Comment: Whatever field represents the longitude, of course. See the question.

Answer (score 6):

You are comparing the latitude & longitude in the database to JUST the latitudes of the submitted values.

Also, you don't need any parentheses in the query, it just makes it cluttered and more complicated.

You want something like:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    items
WHERE
    Latitude >= $southwest_lat AND
    Latitude <= $northeast_lat AND
    Longitude >= $southwest_long AND
    Longitude <= $northeast_long;
```

Answer (score 0):

would

```
SELECT * FROM items 
WHERE Latitude BETWEEN $southwest_lat AND $northeast_lat 
AND Longitude BETWEEN $southwest_lng AND $northeast_lng
```

work better?